# Why are covariance matrices projected by both right and left multiply?

Tags: linear, covariance-matrix, kalman-filter, projection

I've been doing a lot of Kalman filtering work recently. I've derived all the equations starting from a basic linear inverse problem, so strictly speaking I know where everything comes from. I also found [this more pictorial example](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/) instructive for solidifying intuition.

But I can't exactly remember or intuit *why* projecting a matrix, say covariance matrix $P$, from one space to another, by say transformation $H$, is given as $HPH^T$.

It makes perfect sense that you project a vector by left multiplying $Hv$.

Why for matrices is there that extra $H^T$ hanging out, other than that it makes the dimensions work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I look again I see the identity

[image]

And a [quick Wikipedia search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Auto-covariance_matrix_of_real_random_vectors) yields

[image]

This works because the $A$ and $A^T$ can be factored out of the expectations, leaving $A(E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X^T])A^T$, where $E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X^T] = \Sigma$.

Comment: BTW, this also works if the mean of X is not 0!

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: Well, it's already there, in your equation for $\Sigma$. The second term need not disappear. Also keep in mind that the definition of the covariance matrix does not depend on X having zero mean.

Comment: Just like a mathematician to be like "Well it's right there. How don't you see it?" Sorry to be thick, but I still don't see it. Shouldn't that second term need to disappear?

Comment: So I'm not really sure what you are struggling with, as you wrote all the pieces down already. Try to look up the definition of the covariance matrix. They are defined for any random X (well I guess technically for all X that have finite first and second moments), also for nonzero mean. Now, as you did you plug AX into the definition and use linearity of E, and then put it back together into the required for, which is $A\Sigma A^T$

Comment: Or maybe let me turn this around: Why do you think this only works if E[X]=0?

Comment: Because the final expression is given by rewriting the first term, and the second term has to go away, which it only does if E[AX] = A E[X] = 0.

Comment: No, that's exactly the thing. The final expression is not given by the first term only, and the second term must not go away (at least for this to be valid in general)! Again: the covariance is also defined for non-zero mean, and that's why you need this second term. You even gave the definition from Wikipedia!! And this definition does have both terms, right?

Comment: So really all you have to do is pull out the A from the expectation everywhere and that's it.

Comment: @sebhofer: I think what you mean is that, for non-zero mean, the $X$ vector would have to contain elements that had  the mean subtracted out. So, each element of the $X$ vector would be $x_{i}-\mu$. If they didn't have it subtracted out, then Pavel makes the point that the formula would not work.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now. I'm a moron. $cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$, so $cov(X, X^T) \neq E[XX^T]$ unless the mean is zero; it is instead $cov(X, X^T) = E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X^T]$ in the general case. So if you factor $A$ and $A^T$ out of everything in that last expression, then you're gucci.